# In Three.js, whatever I render with WebGL is very blurry compared to the canvas

Tags: canvas, webgl, three.js

I've looked around everywhere and cannot find a reason why this would be.

When rendering with WebGL, everything is "blurry," as though it has been anti-aliased too much and you can't make anything out.  The canvas renderer works as expected.  Particles are also not appearing in the WebGL renderer, although particle systems and normal meshes will.

Comment: The blurriness seemed to go away after restarting the machine.  Particles still won't appear, however.  In the particle system, they're doing weird stuff like not having a transparent background.

http://i.imgur.com/D0Ueg.png

They're transparent as they should be with the canvas renderer.

Comment: @user1477699 `material.transparent = true`.

Answer (score 0):

For the not transparent particles: make sure you have loaded the texture as RGBA (default) and not RGB. `Particle` might also need `transparent` flag set to true.

A wild guess about the bluriness: Chrome has a bug when after some time WebGL viewport starts to go smaller, blurring everything. Opening a new tab fixes it.